# How do you insert a single ligature manually?

Tags: luatex, ligatures, selnolig

We have `\/` and other commands to *prevent* a single ligature manually, e.g.: `shelf\/ful`. But what is the command to insert a single ligature manually? I am using the `\nolig{st}{s|t}` command to prevent all instances of the s-t discretionary ligature in my document; but, while keeping this suppression activated, I want to enable the s-t discretionary ligature manually in one place--the header of pages.

Comment: Have you tried the `\uselig` macro (§4.1.3 of the `selnolig` manual)?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package features four main user macros: `\nolig`, `\keeplig`, `\breaklig`, and `\uselig`.

- `\nolig` and `\keeplig` are meant to be used in the preamble of a document, to create ligature suppression and (re)enabling rules, respecctively, that apply to the whole document.
- `\breaklig` and `\uselig` are meant to be used on a case by case basis within the document. `\uselig` is to `\keeplig` what `\breaklig` is to `\nolig`.

Thus, you could augment the rule

```
\nolig{st}{s|t}
```

with `\uselig{First fast stirring steps}` in the page header in question.